# Compare date to date in cell

Tags: excel, vba

In column A I have dates in the format of "Jan-2016".
In column F I have short text phrases. 
In column J I have names of colors.

I am trying to change to color in column J if conditions are met in column F and A. Currently my code is ignoring the date condition in column A and turning column J to "blue" for every instance of "dog".

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub CompleteKDs()
For MY_ROWS = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Range("F" & MY_ROWS).Value = "dog" And Range("A" & MY_ROWS).Value >= (6 / 1 / 2016) Then
        Range("J" & MY_ROWS).Value = "blue"
    End If
Next MY_ROWS

End Sub
```

Comment: Change your date to be between #'s...`#6/1/2016#`

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks

Comment: Just remember that dates written in this format are in `#m/d/yyyy#` format, even if you are in a locale which uses dd/mm/yyyy format dates (the **proper** way to express dates!! ;) )  The exception would be dates such as #16/3/2016#, which Excel would interpret to be 16 March 2016 because there is no month 16.

Answer (score 0):

Rdster correctly answered: Change your date to be between #'s...#6/1/2016#

Comment: Would use `Format("6/1/2016", "dd/mm/yyyy")` instead and also use `Format(Range("A" & MY_ROWS).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")`. Just change the dd/mm/yyyy to your format, then you are sure that both are formated as the date you want.

Comment: @Niclas - comparing two text fields that have been formatted with day as the high order position will not give good results (e.g. `format("6/2/2016","dd/mm/yyyy")>=format("9/2/2015","dd/mm/yyyy")` will be `False` because "06...." is not > than "09....").  And converting a string to a date (implicit in the first parameter of the `Format`) so that it can then be formatted to a string using a date format with the possible intention of using it as a date is not such a good idea either.